# Meaning of variables and applications in lambda calculus

Tags: logic, induction, definition, lambda-calculus

The [wikipedia definition of lambda terms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambda_calculus#Lambda_terms) is:

> The following three rules give an inductive definition that can be
>   applied to build all syntactically valid lambda terms:
>
> - a variable, $x$, is itself a valid lambda term
> - if $t$ is a lambda term, and $x$ is a variable, then $(\lambda x.t)$ is a lambda term (called a '''lambda abstraction''');
> - if $t$ and $s$ are lambda terms, then $(ts)$ is a lambda term (called an '''application'''). Nothing else is a lambda term. Thus a
>     lambda term is valid if and only if it can be obtained by repeated
>     application of these three rules. However, some parentheses can be
>     omitted according to certain rules. For example, the outermost
>     parentheses are usually not written.

However, I cannot understand what variables are. Are they numbers? Or are they functions?

What is the result of an application? Is it a number or is it a function?

Reading many explanations regarding lambda calculus, I often see expressions like:

$$\lambda x.x+3$$

But, according to the definition above, those expressions are not valid lambda terms, because integers and operators are not valid lambda terms. So I guess I cannot express arithmetic expressions in lambda calculus. How can I describe functions?

Comment: $\lambda$-calculus is pure syntax – everything is just a symbol. But you _can_ actually do arithmetic in $\lambda$-calculus using Church numerals.

Comment: @ZhenLin Church encoding is what I was looking for. If you post it as an answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The point is that $\lambda$-calculus is pure syntax. The symbols are just symbols and don't stand for anything in particular. However, it is possible to do arithmetic in $\lambda$-calculus using [Church numerals](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Church_encoding).

This is not to be confused with the simple notion of $\lambda$-abstraction, which finds use outside $\lambda$-calculus as a convenient way of defining function terms.

Answer (score 4):

Pure $\lambda$-calculus is rather restrictive. Nevertheless, you can extend it to contain "$3$" and "$+$" (either by really extending the language, or perhaps by denoting by $3$ some special lambda term like $\lambda f.\ \lambda x.\ f(f(f x))$).

Variables are unique symbols (most often strings), which make it easier to construct lambda-terms and define the whole affair. Compare for example [De Brujin  index](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Bruijn_index), which uses plain numbers for the same task.

When thinking about lambda-terms, think about ordinary functions, only defined on some weird domain, e.g. for your example it would be

$x \mapsto x+3,$

or using different notation

$$f$$

where

$$f(x) = x+3.$$

Also, note the difference, $f(x)$ is not $f$, that is, $f$ is a function, while $f(x)$ is a symbol $x$ applied to function $f$; in other words you can write $f = x \mapsto x+3$, but $f(x) = x \mapsto x+3$ would be nonsensical (or it could yield falsehood, depending on your interpretation of "$=$", but that's different story).

The type of result of an application depends on a function. For $f$ it would be a number, e.g. $f(4) = 7$, but for a diffrent function like $g$ it could be another function, for example

$$g = y \mapsto (x \mapsto x + y),$$

or in other notation 
$$g(y)(x) = x+y.$$

Now, the result of $g(3)$ is a function, and it happens that $g(3) = (x \mapsto x+3) = f$, or to put it different way $g(3)(x) = x+3 = f(x)$. This happens because $f : \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$, while $g : \mathbb{N} \to (\mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N})$, or as set-theorists would sometimes write $g : \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}^\mathbb{N}$, hence $g(3) : \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$. Of course, in $\lambda$-calculus I could write these applications withouth parentheses, e.g. $g\ 3\ 5 = 8$ (and the equality sign isn't actually good, there are many types of equality, and here it could mean reduction which is yet a different kind of beast than equality).

I hope this helps $\ddot\smile$