# Is Lambda calculus a purely equational theory?

Tags: axioms, lambda-calculus

In a [previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/684089/meaning-of-variables-and-applications-in-lambda-calculus) I have been told that lambda calculs is pure syntax.
I see that Lambda calculus is introduced inductively, but I don't see from what axioms it follows that:
$$(\lambda x.x) M \leadsto_\beta M$$
Because in the reduction above $\lambda x.x$ is seen as a function over Lambda terms.

Can somebody explain me what is the point here?

Comment: Writing $(\lambda x.\ x)M = M$ is wrong (or yields falsehood), those two terms are _not_ equal. I think you would want the [$\beta$-reduction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambda_calculus#.CE.B2-reduction), that is, $(\lambda x.\ x)M \leadsto_\beta M$, however, as the name suggests, reduction is _not_ equality.

Comment: Now your question is changed. The definition of [$\beta$-reduction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambda_calculus#Beta_reduction) clearly states, why $(\lambda x.\ x)M \leadsto_\beta M$.

Comment: I have changed that to remove the wrong equation from the question. Seeing revisions of the question is possibile to see the original form.

Comment: The lambda calculus defines a few equivalence relations. I think it's ok to refer to them as equality.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*Posted as an answer, as requested by the OP.*

Writing $$(λx.\ x)\ M=M$$ is wrong (or yields falsehood), those two terms are not equal.

I think what you want is the [$β$-reduction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambda_calculus#Beta_reduction), that is, 
$$(λx.\ x)\ M\ {\leadsto}_\beta\  M,$$ 
however, as the name suggests, reduction is not equality. In case of $\beta$-reduction, the definition clearly states why $(\lambda x.\ x)\ M\ \leadsto_\beta \ M$, namely $(\lambda x.\ x)\ M$ rewrites to $x[x \mapsto M]$ which is $M$.

I hope this helps $\ddot\smile$

Comment: If I understand correctly in another example $(\lambda x.xx)M$ rewrites to $xx[x \rightarrow M]$ and then to $M$. Am I right?

Comment: @VitalijZadneprovskij No, $xx[x\mapsto M]$ rewrites to $MM$ and what then depends on $M$. E.g. if $M = (\lambda x.\ x\ x)$ then $MM \leadsto_\beta MM$.

Comment: Note that some authors (like Barendregt) use $=$ for equality in the theory generated by the $\lambda$-calculus, so in that case one actually has $(\lambda x.x) M = M$.

Comment: @Guido Right, but then the equality is in fact between equivalence classes of relation that groups terms equivalent in the generated theory.

Comment: Coming back to this, you say "$xx[x \rightarrow M]$ rewrites to $MM$". This is wrong, $xx[x \rightarrow M]$ is *exactly* $MM$, the substitution is **not** a reduction step (unless one works with explicit substitutions like Abadi, Cardelli, Curien and Levy).

Comment: @Guido Yeah, you are right, substitution operator is usually in the meta-language.